# How to recover from FirebaseAuth anonymous error linking to apple credential in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

Apple sign-in has been working well in the app but we recently introduced anonymous auth. this would mean a user can convert their guest account with an apple account.
But this fails when the apple account already exists in the project. Which is the expected behaviour.
Only Firebase provides a credential object to recover from the linking error but in this case it is always `null`
This is the code

```
final credential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(scopes: [
      AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
      AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
    ], nonce: nonce
        // webAuthenticationOptions: WebAuthenticationOptions(
        //   clientId: clientID,
        //   redirectUri: Uri.parse(redirectURL),
        // ),
        );

    final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider('apple.com')
        .credential(idToken: credential.identityToken, rawNonce: rawNonce);


if (usr!.isAnonymous) {
        try {
          // authResult = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser!
          //     .linkWithCredential(oauthCredential);
          authResult =
              await _firebaseAuth.currentUser?.linkWithProvider(appleProvider);
        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          print(e);
          switch (e.code) {
            case "credential-already-in-use":
              cred = e.credential;
              if (cred != null) {
                try {
                  authResult =
                      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(cred);
                  print(authResult.credential);
                } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                  log("err" + e.toString());
                }
              }
              break;
```

As can be seen, I have tried two methods

1. Linking with credential

   ```
     UserCredential? authResult;
     authResult = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser!
         .linkWithCredential(oauthCredential);
   ```
2. Linking with provider

   ```
   UserCredential? authResult;
      AppleAuthProvider appleProvider = AppleAuthProvider();
      appleProvider.addScope('email');
      appleProvider.addScope('fullName');

    authResult =
                  await _firebaseAuth.currentUser?.linkWithProvider(appleProvider);
   ```

In both the error `credential-already-in-use` appears which is correct but the credential to help recover from the error is null. i.e `e.credential` is null.

How should I handle this scenario